# Phonegap geolocation time out

Tags: cordova, geolocation

When I have created a phonegap project: an app with three pages.
When you open the third page, it has to show the current location.

I have added the geolocation plugin via **phonegap local plugin add htps://git...**
I have added the **script tag** and the link to the google **stylesheet**.

Everything is done locally (so not via phonegap build).

Whenever the page opens it ALWAYS returns a time-out (both in emulator as on tablet) Any idea what I am missing? Do I need extra changes to config file? phonegap 3.1

Thank you for your help,
Christophe

```
var options = {
 enableHighAccuracy: true,
 timeout: 20000,
 maximumAge: 10000
};

$(document).on("pageshow", "#nieuweTip", function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError,     options);                    
});

function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
lon = position.coords.longitude;
CreateGoogleMap();      
}

function CreateGoogleMap() {
    var currentposition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

    var mapoptions = {
        zoom:12,
        center: currentposition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapoptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentposition,
        map: map
    }); 
}   

function onGeoError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');            
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled the GPS in your device?

Comment: Try to use the browser's GPS without the plugin.

Comment: GPS is enabled on the device and works (google maps works).

Answer (score -1):

While calling getCurrentPosition remove the last parameter "options" i.e

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);

i tried on Galaxy S2(v 4.1.2) with phonegap 3.3.0 which is working.